# C++ Asterik Graph

Tags: c++, vector, graph

I have recently created a graph made of asterik's and I need to display text next to the asterik's, as show below:

```
SALES BAR CHART
(each * equals £100)
Store 1: **********
Store 2: *****
Store 3: ************
Store 4: ******
Store 5: **
```

This is the code I have written so far and I was wondering if I could have some guidance on how to display the text. Many thanks.

```
#pragma once //stops duplicate library 

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class SalesData
{
private:
    ifstream inputfile;
    ofstream outputfile;
    vector<int> salesrecord;

public:
    void loadDataFromFile(string filename);
    void saveBarChartToFile(string filename);
};

void SalesData::loadDataFromFile(string filename)
{
    int number;
    ifstream sales;
    sales.open("Sales.txt", ios::in);
    while (sales >> number)
    {
        salesrecord.push_back(number);
    }

    cout << "opening file." << endl;

    sales.close();
}

void SalesData::saveBarChartToFile(string filename)
{
    ofstream graph;
    graph.open("Graph.txt", ios::out);
    string stars;
    graph << "SALES BAR CHART" << endl;
    graph << " (each * equals £100)" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < salesrecord.size(); i++)
    {
        stars = "";

        for (int starcount = 1; starcount <= (salesrecord[i] / 100); starcount++)
        {
            stars += "*";
        }

        graph << stars << endl;
    }
    graph.close();
}

int main()
{
    SalesData Mydata;
    Mydata.loadDataFromFile("Sales.txt");
    Mydata.saveBarChartToFile("Graph.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```
graph << stars << endl;
```

to

```
graph << "Store " << (i + 1) << ": " << stars << endl;
```

This change will add the word store followed by the number. The variable `i` is increased by one because `i` is a zero based index and you indicated that you wanted to start the store numbering from 1.

Answer (score 0):

First, that entire loop to generate the stars can be done in a single line using the [std::string constructor (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that takes an integer and a character to repeat.

Second, all you need is text to print before the stars are printed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < salesrecord.size(); i++)
{
    std::string stars(salesrecord[i] / 100, '*');
    graph << "Store " << i + 1 << ": " << stars << endl;
}
```